# How to make a loop appending 20 -20 rows in a tableview when scrolling?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, custom-scrolling

I have a tableview, where I get sometimes 1000 or 40 or sometime even 4 values, but I want that when I got more than 100 values I want to display my array in a 10 - 10 scrolling.

Scrolling the tableview up, I need a scrolling pause after 10 rows are scrolled up, with this code it is giving errors, My array is in [Any] and want to scrolling like Facebook and instagram

I want to get my array into 10 rows first and then I can append the next 10.

```
    var allUserArray = [Any]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    var index = allUserArray.first 
    while index < limit {
    allUserArray.append(index)
    index = index + "1"
  }

  }

  extension AdvanceSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource,           UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allUserArray.count 

}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "advanceSearch") as! AdvanceSearchTableViewCell


    let userData = allUserArray[indexPath.row] as! [String: Any]

    let dob = userData["dob"] as! String
    let age = self.getAgeFromDate(dob: dob)
    let photo1 = userData["photo1"] as? String
    let height = userData["Height"] as? String ?? "null"
    let religion = userData["Religion"] as? String ?? "null"


    cell.userNameLabel.text = "HM- \(userData["ProfileID"] as!   String)"
    cell.userProfessionLabel.text = userData["Profession"] as? String ?? "null"
    cell.userAgeLabel.text = "\(age), \(height), \(religion)"

    if let profileImage = photo1 {
        urlStringOne = "\(USER_IMAGE_BASE_URL)\(profileImage)"
    } else {
        if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "gender") as! String    == "Female") {
            urlStringOne = "\(USER_IMAGE_URL_MALE)"
        } else {
            urlStringOne = "\(USER_IMAGE_URL_FEMALE)"
        }
    }

   loadImage(urlStringOne, cell)

    return cell
}


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.allUserArray.count != nil {

        self.totalEnteries = self.allUserArray.count
        print("idealist/\(self.allUserArray.count)")
        print("total123/\(self.totalEnteries)")

        var entries = allUserArray.count - 1
          print("total-00/\(entries)")

      If indexPath.row == entries {
        print("(----------)")
        if allUserArray.count < totalEnteries {

            var index = allUserArray.count as! String
            self.limit = index + "20"
            while index < self.limit {
                self.allUserArray.append(index)
                index = index + "1"
                }
            self.perform(#selector(self.loadTable), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.0)
          }
        }

}

}
   @objc func loadTable() {
    self.advanceSearchTableView.reloadData()
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll elaborate the **`pagination`** in `tableView` using an example. You can go through it and then implement it in your project.

**1.** Let's assume you've a String array that contains around 500 elements.

```
var allUsers = [String](repeating: "User", count: 500)
```

**2.** Create another `String array` that initially contains first 10 elements from `allUsers` `array`.

```
var dataSource = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addElements() //explained next..
}
```

The `dataSource array` will act as the actual `dataSource` for the `tableView`.

**3.** Let's maintain an `offset` that'll keep track of the `index` from which we need to add next 10 elements, i.e.

```
var nextOffset = 0

func addElements() {
    let newOffset = nextOffset+10
    for i in nextOffset..<newOffset {
        dataSource.append(allUsers[i])
    }
    nextOffset = newOffset
}
```

`addElements()` method simply add next 10 elements starting from the `nextOffset`.

**4.** The `UITableViewDataSource` methods look like,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(dataSource[indexPath.row]) : \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
```

**5.** Now implement `UITableViewDelegate` method - `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentCount = self.dataSource.count
    if currentCount < 500 && indexPath.row == (currentCount-1) { //last row
        self.addData()
        self.setUpLoaderView(toShow: true)
    } else {
        self.setUpLoaderView(toShow: false)
    }
}
```

In the above methods, I've checked if the `cell` is being displayed for the last `row`. If yes, then we add more data to it using `addData()` method and show a `loaderView` at bottom using `setUpLoaderView(toShow:)` method.

**6.** Here is the definition of both the methods,

```
func addData() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        self.addElements()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func setUpLoaderView(toShow: Bool) {
    if toShow {
        self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.loaderMoreView
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}
```

In `addData()` I've added a `delay` of `10 seconds` as per your requirement. So the `loader` will be visible for `10 seconds` before the `tableView` is updated with new data.

**7.** `loaderMoreView` is simply a `UIActivityIndicatorView` that is set as the `tableFooterView`, like:

```
private lazy var loaderMoreView: UIView = {
    let loaderView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
    loaderView.color = UIColor.gray
    loaderView.startAnimating()
    return loaderView
}()
```

Comment: Hi , please elaborate by taking the array of 500 items , how will it is possible to call the whole array of 500 items or I can I just possibly call prefix 10 items of array and then add the arrays next 10 items .

Comment: issue was resolved but with the backend pagination , to save time for loading the tableview .

Comment: Can you please help out ,, how to call the default UIRefreshcontrol at the bottom of table view its coming pull down request ,, I want to load my rows data from bottom.... I want the refresh spinner at bottom of table view

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag variable to check where is the table now on what cell // var showMore : Bool = false
i suggest to convert your array to more friendly type such as String

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

if allUserArray.count > 100 && showMore != true {
    return 20
}else if allUserArray.count > 100 && showMore == true {
    return allUserArray.count 
}else {
    return 20
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if indexpath.row == 20 
    // append new content if any
    // update flag : showMore = true
    // reload table
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I  have implemented this code  in number of rows , but how to append the array that is been left. ?    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Number_Results/\(allUserArray.count)")
       
        if allUserArray.count > 50 {
           return allUserArray.prefix(10).count
        }else {
           return allUserArray.count
        }
      

    }

Comment: In swift you can append array with array.append() or even, oldArray += NewArray

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Bond framework to bind your data. It is built on top of RxSwift. So, in your case, you just need a Mutable Observable Array and bind that array with your tableView.
`let userArray = MutableObservableArray(allUserArray)`

```
userArray.bind(to: collectionView, cellType: UserCell.self) { (cell, name) in
cell.titleLabel.text = name
```

}

Call a function from "willDisplay" and change the values in your array. With this approach, you only need to maintain an array and it will automatically shows up in your tableView.

https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond